# Is it safe to return local struct variable's member variable?

Tags: c++

```
struct SGetWindow
{
    HWND__* pWindow;
};
```

```
SGetWindow getWindow;
EnumWindows(GetWindowProc, reinterpret_cast<LParam>(&getWindow));
return getWindow.pWindow;
```

Using SGetWindow struct as LParam, HWND__* pWindow is successfully updated.

I wonder if this usage of returning member variable of local struct variable is safe.

```
return getwindow.pWindow;
```

Is it safe? or cause undefined behavior?

**EDIT:** I added an image for understanding.

[image: Q1]

I understood that the value of pointer (0x00000000000506D8 or 0x00000000000606D8) 1) is valid after function termination, 2) will be copied. But I don't think that guarantees safeness because the matter it seems is 'access (local struct member variable that no longer exist), and return its value'.

**EDIT2:**

**I was thinking wrong and I was so dumb.**

**According to what I was thinking, even returning local int variable would lead to undefined behavior.** For example,

```
int func()
{
int a = 10;
return a;
}
```

Local variable 'a' no longer valid when function exits. Thus, return value is undefined behavior.

**However, this isn't. Because it is 'return by value' type. The value is copied (somewhere), and the copy process is before local variable goes out of scope.**

Operation sequence would be something like

1. Allocate n bytes for local variable and set its value as 10.

**2. Copy the local variable's value to 'somewhere'.**

3. Function exits and local variables become invalid (reverting EBP).

"Another advantage of return by value is that you can return variables (or expressions) that involve **local variables declared within the function without having to worry about scoping issues. Because the variables are evaluated before the function returns, and a copy of the value is returned to the caller, there are no problems when the function’s variable goes out of scope at the end of the function.**"

https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/74a-returning-values-by-value-reference-and-address/

"**The copy-initialization of the result of the function call is sequenced-before the destruction of all temporaries at the end of expression**, which, in turn, is sequenced-before the destruction of local variables of the block enclosing the return statement."

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return

EBP revert

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Functions_and_Stack_Frames

Shame on me!
Thank you for kind answers by the way.

Comment: Imagine that the struct member is an `int`. Is it safe to return an `int`? Of course.

Comment: What makes you think it might be unsafe? (Are you returning a reference to the member instead of its value?) Why would a member of a local variable lead to a different answer than the same question about the local variable itself?

Comment: Firstly, I thought it would be safe. Then, I've reached to the thought that 'isn't this returning local variable?'. This is why I got confused.

Answer (score 5):

This is safe.

You're returning the value of `getWindow.pWindow`, which happens to be a pointer.  This pointer was populated by a call to `EnumWindows`, not by assigning the address of a local variable.

Answer (score 4):

It's fine, assuming the address in `pWindow` will continue to exist after the function returns. You can't return a pointer to `pWindow` (`&getWindow.pWindow`), but you can return its value (`getWindow.pWindow`), as long as the value remains valid. `pWindow` is destroyed when the function returns but that's okay since its value is being copied. If `pWindow` points to a local variable then you can't do it, but if it points elsewhere then it's safe.